# Here be the plan vs Here is the plan

Tags: difference, grammaticality

Consider these two sentences when some is gonna demonstrate the plan:

1. Here is the plan
2. Here be the plan

What is the difference between them?
Is the second sentence grammatically ok?

Comment: The second sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @JavaLatte - I think the 'be' usage here is a bit more modern?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I't take your word for it. Modern passed me by a long time ago.

Comment: @JavaLatte I hesitate to call it 2020s 'jive talk'.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that 'be' for 'is' (and, also, 'gonna' for 'going to') are street talk, slang, informal, and not standard English. Avoid them in formal writing, school work, etc.